# Invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::dialog (QT error )

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to make a simple QT mainwindow with the button to open a second window or dialog. I followed literally the step from the QT link "Using a Designer UI File in Your Application"  and following the single inheritance example.

But QT gives 4 errors , which you will see a snapshot of below.

Now, what I did is I created a mainwindow in Qt designer, then I added a second form to the project , which will be the second dialog window when a button clicked. Because I created the form manually "mydialog.ui", I added class "mydialog.h and mydialog.cpp" and put the header of "ui-mydialog" in the source file "mydialog.cpp".

I' not sure what am I missing ?

Below is the code :

**- mydialog.h**

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H 
#define MYDIALOG_H
#include<QWidget>

class mydialog ;

namespace Ui {
class mydialog;
}

class mydialog : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit mydialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~mydialog();
private :

    Ui::mydialog *ui;

};

#endif // MYDIALOG_H
```

**- mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_USE_NAMESPACE
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class mydialog;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_Start_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    mydialog *dialog1;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**- mydialog.cpp**

```
#include"mydialog.h"
#include "ui_mydialog.h"


mydialog::mydialog(QWidget *parent) :  QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::mydialog)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}


mydialog::~mydialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**- mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include"mydialog.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    dialog1 = new mydialog ;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete dialog1;
}

void MainWindow::on_Start_clicked()
{

}
```

**- main.cpp**

```
#include"mainwindow.h"
#include<QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**- The .pro file**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-12-17T00:10:58
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TestTool
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    mydialog.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    mydialog.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    mydialog.ui

RESOURCES += \
    misc.qrc
```

**- Qt compilation output error**

[Compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFDco.jpg)

[image]

The generated file Ui_mydialog.h is :

```
#ifndef UI_MYDIALOG_H
#define UI_MYDIALOG_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QDialogButtonBox>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_Dialog
{
public:
    QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox;

    void setupUi(QDialog *Dialog)
    {
        if (Dialog->objectName().isEmpty())
            Dialog->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("Dialog"));
        Dialog->resize(400, 300);
        buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(Dialog);
        buttonBox->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("buttonBox"));
        buttonBox->setGeometry(QRect(30, 240, 341, 32));
        buttonBox->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
        buttonBox->setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok);

        retranslateUi(Dialog);
        QObject::connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), Dialog, SLOT(accept()));
        QObject::connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), Dialog, SLOT(reject()));

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Dialog);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QDialog *Dialog)
    {
        Dialog->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("Dialog", "Dialog", 0));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class Dialog: public Ui_Dialog {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_MYDIALOG_H
```

Comment: You have two classes named `mydialog`: one in global namespace and one (incomplete) in `namespace Ui`.

Comment: @AntonSavin , the QT website doesn't warn against that, or give an answer to how to handle it. I looked at the terminal project in the examples in the QT SDK, and they're doing the same as me. How do you complete the class in the Ui namespace. I only have one class

Comment: Maybe add contents of `ui_mydialog.h` file too.

Comment: @MehrdadMomeny , I thought that gets generated at compile time from the .ui file and then linked with the rest of code

Comment: Yep, but the `Ui::mydialog` class, which is what compiler is complaining about, is there. so maybe you have unintentionally changed the name in designer. and that's the reason for compile error.

Comment: Can you explain why , in `mydialog.h`, you chose to declare two different classes: `Ui::mydialog`, and `mydialog` ?  And why you only provided a class definition for `mydialog` but not for `Ui::mydialog` ?

Comment: @MehrdadMomeny , all I did is follow the example of "terminal" in the QT SDK. In that example, they did the exact same thing as I did in my mind, but the example compiles...clearly I'm missing something

Comment: Please post the `mydialog.ui` and `ui_mydialog.h` files content. There must be a problem with your Ui class name.

Comment: @jpo38   the generated file "ui_mydialog.h" , generates a class called "Ui_Dialog" I was expecting the class to be called "Ui_mydialog". I will post the file in my main post. thanks

Comment: @MehrdadMomeny , yeah I did change the name in Qt designer...how do you update the name, I thought it is simply rename the file on the IDE explorer

Comment: No, there's no connection between name of a class and name of its containing file. And that's true everywhere in c++. If you changed the name in designer, you have to change it in your code as well.

Comment: I solved the problem by just starting a new project...and have a form be created along with the source and header file.

Answer (score 11):

This is because of the diferences between the names in your UI- und C++sourcecode files.
For example if in your UI-sourcecode file you have a name like "StatusBarPart"
but the name of your class in the C++ file is "StatusBar"

```
<class>StatusBarPart</class>
<widget class="QWidget" name="StatusBarPart">
```

---

```
StatusBar::StatusBar(QWidget *parent)
    : PartBase(parent),
      ui(new Ui::StatusBar)
```

then you you get these error message you see.

**Solution**:
You can edit the UI file in some external editor and make the names equal. Save changes. Compile your app. Be happy ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing the name of the ui file with the name of the Ui class (objectName of the top level widget in QtDesigner).

For example, if QtDesigner looks like that:

[image]

You'll get a class names `Ui::CalculatorForm`, whatever the .ui file name is.

Replace `Ui::mydialog` by `Ui::Dialog` (or whatever the class name is in your generated `ui_mydialog.h` file)